# Querying an IntegerField with list of strings using in in Django

Tags: python, django

In Django, if I have a model with an `IntegerField` and query using a string, it's smart enough to cast it

```
class MyClass(Model):
     int_field = IntegerField()
```

So I can do something like

```
# x holds '1234'
MyClass.objects.filter(int_field=x)
```

And this works fine.  Is this guaranteed to work with lists as well?  Consider

```
# y holds ['1234', '5678']
MyClass.object.filter(int_field__in=y)
```

Is this safe in Django?

Comment: Just open up a shell, try if it works and you'll find out.

Comment: I have tried a few test cases (and it worked) but was hoping someone could explain if it is a guarantee to work (and perhaps the mechanism happening behind the scenes)

Answer (score 0):

While Django may cast the strings into integers properly, you can always run a for-loop to be safe:

```
mylist = ['123', '456']
for item in enumerate(mylist):
    try:    
        mylist[item[0]] = int(item[1])
    except:
        continue
```

Now if you were to run `print(list)`, the console would print `[123, 456]` into the console. As you can see, the strings are now integers.

Note: if a string with any letters might somehow make its way into the list, you can always replace the exception's `continue` statement with `raise [error_name_here]` just to be safe.